# c# get JSON file from url

Tags: c#, json

For a few days I am trying to find a way to get [this URL](https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi224735) to a JSON file.

When you visit the above url you see a page with a product on it. This page loads [this URL](https://www.ah.nl/service/rest/delegate?url=%2Fproducten%2Fproduct%2Fwi224735%2Fdoritos-nacho-cheese&_=1513938720642) to a JSON file with all the product information in it.

I want to get this file when I enter the first URL in my C# program so I can extract the data, but I have no idea how to get to this file.

This is how far I got:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetRequest("https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi224735");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



    async static void GetRequest(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //HttpContentHeaders headers = content.Headers;
                    Console.WriteLine(mycontent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this console app reads the header or the HTML and not the JSON file.

Can anybody help me on my way?

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Almost sounds like somebody wants to watch the prices of a competitor

Comment: I don't see whats wrong with my question RiggsFolly. At the moment I have almost no clue in which direction have to think. I am looking at HttpClient at the moment (guess I can at that small peace of code). I am hoping someone here can help me on my way. Not asking lines of code to do for me.
@ Bernard Vander Beken. I can tell you it's not. It's for an application for me and my friends to make a shoppinglist together and it will save and count how much everyone has to pay so at the end of the month we can let everyone pay. If you want to know more about it I you can PM me :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string responseString = string.Empty;
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    responseString = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.ah.nl/service/rest/delegate?url=%2Fproducten%2Fproduct%2Fwi224735%2Fdoritos-nacho-cheese&_=1513938720642");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get the file from the url content-

```
String url="https://www.ah.nl/service/rest/delegate?url=%2Fproducten%2Fproduct%2Fwi224735%2Fdoritos-nacho-cheese&_=1513938720642";
System.Net.WebClient client=new System.Net.WebClient();
String json = client.DownloadString(url);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("fileName.json",json);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Here is a working code-

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmwrA5

Comment: Thanks for the code, but that is not what I am looking for. I figured out how to read a JSON file (using newtonsoft.com atm).
But the problem is how to get the JSON file when I only have this (https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi224735) url

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
//initial URL
var urlStr = @"https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi224735/doritos-nacho-cheese";
//The endpoint to get JSON
var delegateEndpoint = @"https://www.ah.nl/service/rest/delegate";

var urlParam = new Uri(urlStr).PathAndQuery;

var address =
    $"{delegateEndpoint}?url={Uri.EscapeDataString(urlParam)}";
string json;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    json = client.DownloadString(address).Dump();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This almost the solution. I only need the last number in the url, but Andrii pointed out that I can use the ID in the cookie. Hopefully I can combine those the get the proper url.

Comment: That last number is not important, you'll get the same response.

Answer (score 1):

The (B) URL contains last parameter. This last parameter you can take from Cookies:http://prntscr.com/hqxvcu
So, you can try to make this request using HttlClient (https://forums.asp.net/t/2098855.aspx?HTTP+Get+request+in+C+net)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did not find that id, thanks for pointing out, but it looks like its not the same as the (B) url parameter at the end.

Comment: Hmm interesting. The number is not the same, but it looks like its working anyway.

Comment: Basically, that id in cookies is combined from 2 parts divided by ".". So, you can even parse it if needed